# how to add columns data in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

in sql server 2008, i have two columns productu_code,quantity how to add quantity when product is same

```
      ______________________
      |productcode|quantity|
      ----------------------
      |FH5004     |  8     |
      |FH5016     |  4     |
      |FH5029     |  2     |
      |FH5004     |  6     |
      |FH5016     |  2     |
      |____________________|

  can you help me, thank you.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM table_name GROUP BY ProductCode
```

Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT productcode, 
       sum(quantity) as total_quantity
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY productcode
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this SQL:

```
SELECT productcode, SUM(quantity) as total_quantity
FROM Table t1
GROUP BY productcode
```